# Yup validation with formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am using formik and yup together . This is my schema

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
const phoneRegExp = /^((\\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \\-]*)|(\\([0-9]{2,3}\\)[ \\-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \\-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \\-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/
export const employee_schema = Yup.object({
    branch_id: Yup.number().required("Please Select Branch"),
    position_id: Yup.number().required("Please Select Position"),
    first_name: Yup.string().required("First Name is required"),
    last_name: Yup.string().required("Last Name is required"),
    email: Yup.string().email().required("Please enter your email"),
    password: Yup.string().min(6).required("Please enter your password"),
    phone: Yup.string().matches(phoneRegExp ,'Phone number is not valid').required("Phone Number is required"),
    alternative_phone: Yup.string().matches(phoneRegExp, 'Phone number is not valid').required("Phone Number is required"),
    employment_type: Yup.number().required("Please Select Employement Type"),
    department_id: Yup.number().required("Please Select Department"),
    hire_date: Yup.date().required("Please Select Hire Date"),
    monthly_work_hours:  Yup.number().required("Monthly Work Hours is required"),
    pay_frequency: Yup.number().required("Pay Frequency is required"),
    report_to: Yup.string().when("position_id", {
        is: (value) => value !== 12,
        then: Yup.string().required("Report to is required"),
        otherwise: Yup.string(),
      }),
});
```

Now my problem is when I include this report_to validation in my schema, all my current validations stop working.

This is my formik initalizer

```
  const {
    values,
    handleBlur,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    errors,
    touched,
  } = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema: employee_schema,
    validateOnChange: true,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      saveEmp(values);
    },
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
const {
    values,
    handleBlur,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    errors,
    touched,
  } = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema: employee_schema,
    validateOnChange: true,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      saveEmp(values);
    },
})
```